# Adding rows to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of part numbers and the collection they belong to. I'm lost at how to add n-1 number of rows where n is the number of that part's collections that are in the dataframe and then add the other part numbers to a column next to that part number.

For example, this:

[image]

would become:

[image]

Can anybody please help me with this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code).

Comment: refer [df.explode()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

Comment: @Agnij How does that help in this case? Please post an answer if you've got one!

Comment: @wjandrea Oh sorry. I will do as you suggest in the future. Thank you for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

Do a cross `merge` and then drop rows where `Part No` is the same:

```
output = df.merge(df["Part No."].rename("Second No."), how="cross")
output = output[output["Part No."]!=output["Second No."]].reset_index(drop=True)

>>> output

   Part No.    Collection Second No.
0    ABCD26  Collection 1     ABCD30
1    ABCD26  Collection 1     EFGH26
2    ABCD26  Collection 1     EFGH30
3    ABCD30  Collection 1     ABCD26
4    ABCD30  Collection 1     EFGH26
5    ABCD30  Collection 1     EFGH30
6    EFGH26  Collection 1     ABCD26
7    EFGH26  Collection 1     ABCD30
8    EFGH26  Collection 1     EFGH30
9    EFGH30  Collection 1     ABCD26
10   EFGH30  Collection 1     ABCD30
11   EFGH30  Collection 1     EFGH26
```

###### Input df:

```
>>> df

  Part No.    Collection
0   ABCD26  Collection 1
1   ABCD30  Collection 1
2   EFGH26  Collection 1
3   EFGH30  Collection 1
```